# Tensorflow variable is empty

Tags: python, tensorflow

My code is as follows:

```
optimizer_G = tf.train.AdamOptimizer( learning_rate=learning_rate )
grads_vars_G = optimizer_G.compute_gradients( loss_G, var_list=var_G)
grads_vars_G = map(lambda gv: [tf.clip_by_value(gv[0], -10., 10.), gv[1]], grads_vars_G)
train_op_G = optimizer_G.apply_gradients( grads_vars_G )
```

Gives the following error:

```
File "f_train.py", line 101, in <module>
train_op_G = optimizer_G.apply_gradients( grads_vars_G )   
File "/home/wzx/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/tensorflow/python/training/optimizer.py",
line 380, in apply_gradients
raise ValueError("No variables provided.") ValueError: No variables provided.
```

I printed the `grads_vars_G` is empty, I do not know why the `grads_vars_G` is empty.

tensorflow version is 1.0.1-gpu,  python 3.5.
The error is `ValueError: No variables provided`.
I had searched many way to solve, and none succeeds.

So please help me solve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please indicate which line #380 is.

Comment: Looks to me as though `grads_vars_G` is empty. Is it?

Comment: The 380 line is the optimzer.py in tensorflow file,this error is my code created,my code error is only in 101 line.@Noel Widmer

Comment: I printed the grads_vars_G is empty,I do not know why the grads_vars_G is empty,How should I change my code,please help me.@BoarGules

Comment: We don't know what `loss_G` or `var_G` are, so we can't give more clear information.

Comment: My loss_G and var_G are as follow:
loss_G += weight_decay_rate * tf.reduce_mean(tf.stack( map(lambda x: tf.nn.l2_loss(x), W_G))),,,,
var_G = filter( lambda x: x.name.startswith('GEN'), tf.trainable_variables())